# How do i connect to a dapp using walletconnect url using safe account?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I was building a smartwallet using safe sdk. How can i connect to dapps using their walletconnect url to my safe account that i deployed in the wallet i created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.